# How do I link this Bootstrap Javascript with a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks this "New note" button it will create a modal which allows them add a new note. So for this, i need this modal to have the notes_controller => 'new' action. But I am not really sure how to go about this. Here is what I have so far:

```
#views/websites/show.html.erb (not whole file)
<div class="tab-pane" id="notes"><%= render 'notes/index' %><br /> 
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  New note
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want it to on click of this button load the new_note action from the notes controller, how would I go about doing this? I read a few of the other similar questions but could not get a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're trying to do, you have two ways:

1) Create additional ajax call, something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-target=#myModal]', function() {
  $.get(#{new_note_path.to_json}, function(data) {
    // work with data here
  })
})
```

2) Add `data-remote` to your link, which allows you to load modal content via ajax. You can read about modal options here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals